# MIPS function with multiple arguments

Tags: function, mips32, qtspim

I know how to make a function in MIPS that takes in 4 arguments because I know I can just put the arguments into the registers $a0-$a3. But suppose you want more than 4 arguments, how do you get around the fact that there is only 4 argument registers in MIPS ($a0-$a3)?

Answer (score 4):

There are a few different ways to do this, each with its own tradeoffs: (1) using the mips ABI, (2) using your own internal register conventions, or (3) using a C-like struct

---

**The mips ABI:**

The mips ABI [like most other arches], when you run out of argument registers, the remaining arguments are pushed onto the stack.

Consider the following C program:

```
void
callee(int a,int b,int c,int d,int e,int f)
{
}

void
caller(void)
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    int e;
    int f;

    callee(a,b,c,d,e,f);
}
```

The mips ABI equivalent would look like:

```
caller:
    addiu   $sp,$sp,-8              # space for e,f

    lw      $t0,f
    sw      $t0,4($sp)

    lw      $t0,e
    sw      $t0,0($sp)

    lw      $a3,d
    lw      $a2,c
    lw      $a1,b
    lw      $a0,a

    jal     callee
    addiu   $sp,$sp,8               # remove space for e,f

    jr      $ra

callee:
    addiu   $sp,$sp,-4
    sw      $ra,0($sp)

    move    $t0,$a0                 # get a
    move    $t1,$a1                 # get b
    move    $t2,$a2                 # get c
    move    $t3,$a3                 # get d
    lw      $t4,4($sp)              # get e
    lw      $t5,8($sp)              # get f

    # ...

    lw      $ra,0($sp)
    addiu   $sp,$sp,4
    jr      $ra
```

---

**Self contained functions:**

If your functions are self contained within the program [i.e. you aren't calling external ABI conformant functions], you can pass arguments in just about any register you wish:

```
caller:
    lw      $s7,f
    lw      $s6,e

    lw      $a3,d
    lw      $a2,c
    lw      $a1,b
    lw      $a0,a

    jal     callee

    jr      $ra

callee:
    addiu   $sp,$sp,-4
    sw      $ra,0($sp)

    move    $t0,$a0                 # get a
    move    $t1,$a1                 # get b
    move    $t2,$a2                 # get c
    move    $t3,$a3                 # get d
    move    $t4,$s6                 # get e
    move    $t5,$s7                 # get f

    # ...

    lw      $ra,0($sp)
    addiu   $sp,$sp,4
    jr      $ra
```

---

**Using a C struct:**

Like in C, you can pass many things around in a struct:

```
struct args {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    int e;
    int f;
};

void
callee(struct args *av)
{
    int tmp;

    tmp = av->a;
    tmp = av->b;
    tmp = av->c;
    tmp = av->d;
    tmp = av->e;
    tmp = av->f;
}

void
caller(void)
{
    struct args args;

    args.a = 1;
    args.b = 2;
    args.c = 3;
    args.d = 4;
    args.e = 5;
    args.f = 6;

    callee(&args);
}
```

The asm equivalent of a C struct is to use equates to offsets from a base register:

```
# offsets within "struct"
a = 0
b = 4
c = 8
d = 12
e = 16
f = 20

caller:
    la      $a0,args

    li      $t0,1
    sw      $t0,a($a0)

    li      $t0,2
    sw      $t0,b($a0)

    li      $t0,3
    sw      $t0,c($a0)

    li      $t0,4
    sw      $t0,d($a0)

    li      $t0,5
    sw      $t0,e($a0)

    li      $t0,3
    sw      $t0,f($a0)

    jal     callee

    jr      $ra

callee:
    addiu   $sp,$sp,-4
    sw      $ra,0($sp)

    lw      $t0,a($a0)              # get a
    lw      $t1,b($a0)              # get b
    lw      $t2,c($a0)              # get c
    lw      $t3,d($a0)              # get d
    lw      $t4,e($a0)              # get e
    lw      $t5,f($a0)              # get f

    # ...

    lw      $ra,0($sp)
    addiu   $sp,$sp,4
    jr      $ra
```

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful.

Comment: Is addiu with -8 possible?

Comment: @GertjanBrouwer I think _this_ answer of mine may be what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40090168/andi-vs-addi-instruction-in-mips-with-negative-immediate-constant/40118189#40118189