# andi vs. addi instruction in MIPS with negative immediate constant

Tags: assembly, mips, sign-extension, zero-extension, immediate-operand

**Assume $t2=`0x55555550`, then executing the following instruction:**

```
andi $t2, $t2, -1
```

**$t2 becomes `0x0005550`**

This is confirmed by the MIPS emulator<sup>1</sup>

However, it is not what I expected. I think the answer should be 0x55555550 & 0xFFFFFFFF = 0x55555550.
I think the constant -1 was sign extended to 0xFFFFFFFF before the and logic. But it appears that the answer was 0x55555550 & 0x0000FFFF

Why -1 is sign extended to 0x0000FFFF instead of 0xFFFFFFFF

---

Footnote 1: Editor's note: MARS with "extended pseudo-instructions" enabled does expand this to multiple instructions to generate `0xffffffff` in a tmp register, thus leaving `$t2` unchanged.  Otherwise MARS and SPIM both reject it with an error as not encodeable.  Other assemblers may differ.

Comment: Your expectation for value is correct. _Which_ mips emulator? I've tested this in both `mars` and `spim` [single stepping] and they _both_ produce `0x5555554F`. Are you _sure_ you are preloading the original value correctly (e.g. `li $t2,0x55555550`)? If you are _not_ checking the post `addi` value with single step, how are you getting the `5550` value? At worst, with 16 bit truncation, you'd get `554F`. This is such a basic operation, you can verify it on a hex calculator.

Comment: @CraigEstey My big big apology. I was dizzy late last night and totally have my thought wrong. It should be andi instead of addi. Could you please take some time to read my question again. Sorry.......

Comment: Well, MIPS immediate values _are_ 16-bits wide, anyway.

Comment: @LinYuCheng I hope you're feeling better. Again, your expectation for value is correct. But, you're misreading the emulator results. See my answer as to what is really going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Your *expectation* is correct, but your interpretation of your experimental results is *not***

> $t2 becomes 0x0005550 This is confirmed by the MIPS emulator.

No, this is incorrect. So, one of the following:

1. Somehow, you're misreading what the emulator is doing. The actual value from the emulator *is* what you *expected* it to be.
2. *Or*, you don't have `0x55555550` in `$t2` *before* the `andi` as you assume, but `0x5550` instead (i.e.) your test program doesn't set up `$t2` correctly.

> However, it is not what I expected. I think the answer should be 0x55555550 & 0xFFFFFFFF = 0x55555550. I think the constant -1 was sign extended to 0xFFFFFFFF before the and logic.

Yes, this *is* correct. And, I'll explain what is happening and why below.

> But it appears that the answer was 0x55555550 & 0x0000FFFF. Why -1 is sign extended to 0x0000FFFF instead of 0xFFFFFFFF

It *wasn't*. It *was* sign extended to `0xFFFFFFFF`. Again, you're reading the experimental results incorrectly [or your test program has a bug].

---

**`mips` simulators and assemblers have *pseudo ops***.

These are instructions that may or may not exist as real, physical instructions. However, they are interpreted by the assembler to generate a sequence of physical/real instructions.

An example of a "pure" pseudo-op is `li` ("load immediate"). It has *no* corresponding instruction, but usually generates a two instruction sequence: `lui`, `ori` (which *are* physical instructions).

Pseudo-ops should *not* be confused with assembler *directives*, such as `.text`, `.data`, `.word`, `.eqv`, etc.

Some pseudo-ops can overlap with actual physical instructions. That is what is happening with your example.

In fact, the assembler examines *any* given instruction as a *potential* pseudo-op. It may determine that in can fulfill the *intent* with a single physical instruction. If not, it will generate a 1-3 instruction sequence and may use the [reserved] `$at` register [which is `$1`] as part of that sequence.

In `mars`, to see the actual real instructions, look in the `Basic` column of the source window.

For the sake of the completeness of my answer, all that follows is prefaced by the top comments.

I've created three example programs:

1. The `addi` as in your original post
2. The `andi` as in your corrected post
3. An `andi` that uses an *unsigned* argument

---

(1) Here is the assembler source for your original question using `addi`:

```
    .text
    .globl  main
main:
    li      $t2,0x55555550
    addi    $t3,$t2,-1
    nop
```

Here is how `mars` interpreted it:

```
 Address    Code        Basic                     Source

0x00400000  0x3c015555  lui $1,0x00005555         4     li      $t2,0x55555550
0x00400004  0x342a5550  ori $10,$1,0x00005550
0x00400008  0x214bffff  addi $11,$10,0xffffffff   5     addi    $t3,$t2,-1
0x0040000c  0x00000000  nop                       6     nop
```

`addi` will *sign extend* its 16 bit immediate, so we have `0xFFFFFFFF`. Then, doing a *two's complement* add operation, we have a final result of `0x5555554F`

Thus, the assembler didn't need to generate extra instructions for the `addi`, so the `addi` *pseudo-op* generated a single *real* `addi`

---

(2) Here is the `andi` source:

```
    .text
    .globl  main
main:
    li      $t2,0x55555550
    andi    $t3,$t2,-1
    nop
```

Here is the assembly:

```
 Address    Code        Basic                     Source

0x00400000  0x3c015555  lui $1,0x00005555         4     li      $t2,0x55555550
0x00400004  0x342a5550  ori $10,$1,0x00005550
0x00400008  0x3c01ffff  lui $1,0xffffffff         5     andi    $t3,$t2,-1
0x0040000c  0x3421ffff  ori $1,$1,0x0000ffff
0x00400010  0x01415824  and $11,$10,$1
0x00400014  0x00000000  nop                       6     nop
```

*Whoa!* What happened? The `andi` generated three instructions.

A *real* `andi` instruction does *not* sign extend its immediate argument. So, the largest *unsigned* value we can use in a real `andi` is `0xFFFF`

But, by specifying `-1`, we told the assembler that we *did* want sign extension (i.e. `0xFFFFFFFF`)

So, the assembler could *not* fulfull the intent with a single instruction and we get the sequence above. And the generated sequence could *not* use `andi` but had to use the register form: `and`. Here is the `andi` generated code converted back into more friendly asm source:

```
    lui     $at,0xFFFF
    ori     $at,$at,0xFFFF
    and     $t3,$t2,$at
```

As to result, we're anding `0x55555550` and `0xFFFFFFFF` which is a [still unchanged] value of `0x55555550`

---

(3) Here is the source for an *unsigned* version of `andi`:

```
    .text
    .globl  main
main:
    li      $t2,0x55555550
    andi    $t3,$t2,0xFFFF
    nop
```

Here is the assembler output:

```
 Address    Code        Basic                     Source

0x00400000  0x3c015555  lui $1,0x00005555         4     li      $t2,0x55555550
0x00400004  0x342a5550  ori $10,$1,0x00005550
0x00400008  0x314bffff  andi $11,$10,0x0000ffff   5     andi    $t3,$t2,0xFFFF
0x0040000c  0x00000000  nop                       6     nop
```

When the assembler sees that we're using a hex constant (i.e. the `0x` prefix), it tries to fulfill the value as an *unsigned* operation. So, it doesn't need to sign extend. And, the real `andi` can fulfill the request.

The result of this is `0x5550`

Note that if we had used a mask value of `0x1FFFF`, that would be unsigned. But, it's larger than 16 bits, so the assembler would generate a multi-instruction sequence to fulfill the request.

And, the result here would be `0x15550`

Comment: Thanks for your excellent explanation. I got it clear now. It seems I have to read more about the "physical" machine code.

Comment: You're welcome. Here's a good list of instructions: http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html As an example, notice that there are six real single register forms for branch: `bltz/blez/beqz/bnez/bgez/bgtz`. But, only two real two register versions: `bne/beq`. The remaining [not shown] `blt/ble/bge/bgt` are pseudo ops. They use `slt` in some fashion to set `$at`. BTW, it customary to upvote a good answer and accept the best one.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [specification](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3410/2008fa/mips_vol2.pdf), immediate values are 16-bit wide.

Therefore, `andi $t2, $t2, -1` can be read as `andi $t2, $t2, 0xFFFF`.

All logical operations treat the immediate as a bitstring, and zero-extend it to 32-bits.

Comment: This is correct as far a real/physical instruction goes. But, mips simulators/assemblers interpret instructions as pseudo-ops and may generate something completely different. In OP's code, the assembler _doesn't_ generate a real `andi`. It generates a 3 instruction sequence. See my answer for details.

Comment: @CraigEstey: I wouldn't be surprised if some assembler simply truncates `-1` to fit in a zero-extended immediate.  The current versions of SPIM and MARS don't, though.  MARS with extended pseudo-instructions accepts it as a pseudo, otherwise MARS and SPIM both reject `-1`.  So does clang's built-in assembler.  (Also, this would be a better answer if it mentioned that other MIPS instruction sign-extend their immediate, including `addiu`. [What does "extend immediate to 32 bits" mean in MIPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55290060))

Comment: @PeterCordes This is covered in my answer [for `andi`, at least]. If you do, `andi $t2,0xFFFF`, you get a real `andi` that _is_ truncated to 16 bits (i.e. `0x0000FFFF`). If you do, `andi $t2,-1`, `mars` treats this as pseudo op, and generates three instructions to produce a full, sign extended, 32 bit `and` (equivalent to `0xFFFFFFFF`).

Answer (score 0):

[MIPS Reference Sheet](https://www.docsity.com/documents/pages/2016/09/28/029d738d4a99fac363ee4dcf3270d3c0.png)

From this reference sheet, for the **andi** instruction, it clearly says that sign extension done on the immediate is zero extension. It is similar for the **ori** instruction as well. For the sequence of operations you are using, this is exactly what MIPS is supposed to do.
For doing what you intend to do, you should store 0xFFFFFFFF in some other register, and use "**and**" operation.